# Why was my answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Please don't take this the wrong way, I am not judging but just trying to understand how to improve myself and how to become a more helpful member to this community.

I saw a question on MySQL and there was no answer and I answered.
Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111697/mysql-exception

After one upvote a moderator deleted my answer and the question is still there with no answer.

I read the Faq about answer deletions but can't find a reason for the deletion. Can anyone guide me to improve my answers?

Comment: The question probably won't be open much longer...

Comment: I can't help you with your question, but for what it's worth well done on the attitude. It's nice to see someone here honestly interested in figuring out what happened and how to improve.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the deletion - I presume it was because you posted a follow-up question to it. I'm sure you could raise a flag and argue against the deletion. However, as Josh says, the question will probably not be around much longer, so it's probably not worth the effort. +1 for attitude from me, too, though!

Comment: +1 - This is a great example of how to bring a question to Meta SO! ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you were trying to engage in a conversation, so your "answer" got flagged.  I do look at every flagged answer before I delete it, but I don't always look at the entire post for context.

I've converted your answer to a comment.

Comment: Really thank you very much I got it now and I will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The text of your answer was:

---

> out of range value for column 'mobile'
>
> means you are trying to write a value to field mobile which is not in acceptable range you defined.
>
> what is your table structure? and what is the value you are trying to insert to that field.ü

---

It was deleted because it wasn't an answer.  You are asking for additional information, which is better asked in a comment.

Comment: Indeed, the mod should have turned it into comment..

Comment: Well, the second part of the answer is a question. The first part, not necessarily. Anyway, not worth fighting over because the question will be nuked soon

Comment: Yeah, other than the last line that actually looks like a perfectly acceptable answer to the question, considering how terrible the question was.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you were trying to be helpful, which is awesome, but if you're going to seek clarification, you should use a comment, not an answer.

Answers are for when you *know* the answer (or an answer) that will actually solve the problem. I'm confident that, if the asker included more details in the question, you'd be able to answer the question, but in this case, if you have questions for the asker, use the comments. ;)

From the [Deletion section of the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion):

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are …
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

Hope this helps!

Comment: So thanks, I understand the difference now and I will be more carefull about it.